# How can I transform a multi-index pivot table to a nested list including part of the index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray, multi-index

**Update:** I really tried to have my example representative, turns out it wasn't. I updated the question as the spirit is the same, just a little more complicated.

---

I'm working with a big Pandas dataset that I want to extract data from for plotting. This small example should illustrate it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': pd.Categorical(['Carl', 'Carl', 'Carl', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Tina',
                                           'Carl', 'Carl', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Carl', 'Carl'] * 2),
                   'DayOfYear': [51, 20, 20, 1, 70, 140, 77, 190, 210, 365, 260, 333] * 2,
                   'Type': pd.Categorical(['Weight'] * 12 + ['Height'] * 12),
                   'Number': [60.3, 61.0, 59.8, 77.1, 74.0, 73.4, 58.2, 60.6, 73.6, 75.0, 59.7, 60.5,
                              172.3, 172.3, 172.3, 165.9, 165.9, 165.9,
                              172.3, 172.3, 165.9, 165.9, 172.3, 172.3],
                  })
```

I started with grouping but changed to pivot tables as the workflow seems easier—should be the same, right? I tried many things and so far this got me closest to my goal:

```py
p = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name', 'DayOfYear'], values='Number', columns='Type')
```

[image: the outcome of pivoting]

For plotting, the remaining part would be transforming that to:

```py
what_bqplot_needs_x = [
        [20, 51, 77, 190, 260, 333],
        [1, 70, 140, 210, 365],
        [20, 51, 77, 190, 260, 333],
        [1, 70, 140, 210, 365],
]
what_bqplot_needs_y = [
        [60.4, 60.3, 58.2, 60.6, 59.7, 60.5],
        [77.1, 74.0, 73.4, 73.6, 75.0],
        [172.3] * 6,
        [165.9] * 5,
]
```

I don't seem to grasp/get along with Pandas’ [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) and I really would like to understand how to massage a `DataFrame` to get there.

It doesn't have to be a list of lists, a `ndarray` array would also do.

---

I tried adapting [jezrael’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63030985/581002), but the very first `.reset_index(level=1)` already crashes with:

```
TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) values of `Weight` are aggregates if duplicates (like here first 2 rows):

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name', 'DayOfYear'], values='Weight')
```

Then is used [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with aggregate lists in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = df.reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print (df1)
                        DayOfYear                                Weight
Name                                                                   
Carl  [20, 51, 77, 190, 260, 333]  [60.4, 60.3, 58.2, 60.6, 59.7, 60.5]
Tina       [1, 70, 140, 210, 365]        [77.1, 74.0, 73.4, 73.6, 75.0]
```

And last convert output to lists:

```
what_i_want_x = df1['DayOfYear'].tolist()
what_i_want_y = df1['Weight'].tolist()

print (what_i_want_x)
[[20, 51, 77, 190, 260, 333], [1, 70, 140, 210, 365]]

print (what_i_want_y)
[[60.4, 60.3, 58.2, 60.6, 59.7, 60.5], [77.1, 74.0, 73.4, 73.6, 75.0]]
```

EDIT:

```
p = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name', 'DayOfYear'], values='Number', columns='Type')
print (p)
Type            Height  Weight
Name DayOfYear                
Carl 20          172.3    60.4
     51          172.3    60.3
     77          172.3    58.2
     190         172.3    60.6
     260         172.3    59.7
     333         172.3    60.5
Tina 1           165.9    77.1
     70          165.9    74.0
     140         165.9    73.4
     210         165.9    73.6
     365         165.9    75.0
     
df1 = p.rename(columns=str).reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print (df1)
Type                    DayOfYear                                      Height  \
Name                                                                            
Carl  [20, 51, 77, 190, 260, 333]  [172.3, 172.3, 172.3, 172.3, 172.3, 172.3]   
Tina       [1, 70, 140, 210, 365]         [165.9, 165.9, 165.9, 165.9, 165.9]   

Type                                Weight  
Name                                        
Carl  [60.4, 60.3, 58.2, 60.6, 59.7, 60.5]  
Tina        [77.1, 74.0, 73.4, 73.6, 75.0]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I had the outputs wrong. I don't want the 333 dropped. I edited the question to what I expect. Your output is not correct.

Comment: @primfaktor - Then it is simplier, answer was edited.

Comment: Well that's one way to fix it although it seems a little hacky to me.

Comment: Is there no way to just _extract_ that to a new “dimension”?

Comment: @primfaktor - not sure if understand, what is dimmension?

Comment: Something similar to numpy’s `np.ones((3, 4)).reshape(3, 2, 2)`.

Comment: @primfaktor - Problem is you cannot reshape like `np.ones((3, 4)).reshape(3, 2, 2)` - pandas to 3d numpy array, because different lengths of lists. Problem with error in last paragraph is possible solve by converting columns names to strings after pivoting, answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

jezrael was quickier, but here you have another option using pandas `.groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': pd.Categorical(['Carl', 'Carl', 'Carl', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Tina',
                                           'Carl', 'Carl', 'Tina', 'Tina', 'Carl', 'Carl']),
                   'DayOfYear': [20, 20, 51, 1, 70, 140, 77, 190, 210, 365, 260, 333],
                   'Weight': [61.0, 59.8, 60.3, 77.1, 74.0, 73.4, 58.2, 60.6, 73.6, 75.0, 59.7, 60.5]
                  })

df2 = df.groupby(["Name", "DayOfYear"]).mean().dropna().reset_index()
what_i_want_x = [list(df2["DayOfYear"][df2["Name"] == name_selected]) for name_selected in np.unique(df2["Name"])]

print(what_i_want_x)
[[20, 51, 77, 190, 260, 333], [1, 70, 140, 210, 365]]

what_i_want_y = [list(df2["Weight"][df2["Name"] == name_selected]) for name_selected in np.unique(df2["Name"])]

print(what_i_want_y )
[[60.4, 60.3, 58.2, 60.6, 59.7, 60.5], [77.1, 74.0, 73.4, 73.6, 75.0]]
```

Comment: Works. But doesn't that re-do a lot of the computation that `pivot_table`/`groupby` already did?

Comment: I don't use `pivot_table` in this solution. Regarding computation, we do first the `groupby` and then we just pass through the indexes. This is a workaround, I'm pretty sure it is possible to do it using `level` as you tried (unless this is a bug/feature), but I don't see it right now.

Comment: I know, but `pivot_table` and `groupby` should be equivalent.